# What could be the cause of slow performance in both confirm sale.order and validate stock.picking?

Tags: performance, debugging, odoo, odoo-14

In one of my databases that has more than 10k products and thousands of contacts, sale orders, and inventory transfers, it has a weird slow performance every time the Confirm (`action_sale_ok`) button is clicked in `sale.order`, and the same slow performance also happens when processing Validate (`button_validate`) button in `stock.picking`.

The issue is that the page takes more than 10 seconds to finish the process while displaying a loading screen that disables the user to do anything.

What could be the cause of this problem?

I tried debugging in many places in `stock.picking`, and `stock.move` that relates to `button_validate`, but found nothing. It seems like it is something that is executed after the validation process that I can't trace to it -- maybe some `depend` methods.

Comment: If you have custom modules override these buttons, you need to check them.

Comment: @WaleedMohsen I checked all of them that relate to the stock.picking and stock.move. Still, found nothing useful.

Comment: Check this Performance Issues? Here are the Best Solutions https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5jT5eoCZH6U

Comment: @WaleedMohsen That's very nice video. Do you happen to know where I can find the Profiling feature in the client side (not the python @profile) for Odoo 14? I'm using Odoo 14 CE.

Comment: You can check the Odoo documentation https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/howtos/profilecode.html

Comment: @WaleedMohsen I already tried all of them in the link, but what I meant is the "Enable Profiling" option in the video at 10:35. I can't seem to find it in my environment.

Comment: @holydragon Unfortunately, it looks like the "Enable profiling" option was added as a part of Odoo 15 ([source](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/f65e3d9d21d269058dd842a4319b5b2242df103e/addons/web/static/src/core/debug/profiling/profiling_item.xml#L11)).